# How should I capitalize Perl?

Tags: perl, coding-style, capitalization

PERL? Perl? perl? What's good style?

I know the answer—I just wanted to make sure the question was out there and questioners were aware that there is a correct form.

Comment: Capitalize it any way you want - user "brian d foy" will probably come by and correct it for you. ;)

Comment: I believe you're supposed to prefix it with a 'The' and refer to it in the plural. ie: I was coding The Perls this morning.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70496/ concerning repeatedly deleted comments on this thread.

Comment: I've now asked the same about RUBY :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053240/how-should-i-capitalize-ruby

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The correct casing is "Perl" for the language and "perl" for the executable. Using "PERL" flags you as someone who isn't particularly familiar with the language or community.

See also [What's the difference between "perl" and "Perl"?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq1.html#What%27s-the-difference-between-%22perl%22-and-%22Perl%22?) in [perlfaq1](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq1.html).

Comment: Actually, I'd suggest definite familiarity with older versions of the language - the name *used* to be written this way in the manual page for perl 4, along with an explanation that it was an acronym for "practical extraction and reporting language" (ref: http://www-cgi.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/perl-man) many of us older users ignore the revisionist complaints that it isn't an acronym and therefore shouldn't be capitalised.

Answer (score 13):

Quoting [the Perl article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl#Name).

> The name is normally capitalized (Perl) when referring to the language and uncapitalized (perl) when referring to the interpreter program itself since Unix-like file systems are case-sensitive. Before the release of the first edition of Programming Perl, it was common to refer to the language as perl; Randal L. Schwartz, however, capitalised the language's name in the book to make it stand out better when typeset. The case distinction was subsequently adopted by the community.

Also check the [perlfaq about this question](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq1.html#What's-the-difference-between-%22perl%22-and-%22Perl%22%3f).

Comment: Here's the link to perlfaq:
http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq1.html#What's-the-difference-between-%22perl%22-and-%22Perl%22%3f

Answer (score 8):

Here's the answer from [perlfaq1](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq1.html):

> What's the difference between "perl"
>   and "Perl"?
>
> One bit.  Oh, you weren't talking
>   ASCII? :-) Larry now uses "Perl" to
>   signify the language proper and "perl"
>   the implementation of it, i.e. the
>   current interpreter.  Hence Tom's quip
>   that "Nothing but perl can parse
>   Perl."  You may or may not choose to
>   follow this usage.  For example,
>   parallelism means "awk and perl" and
>   "Python and Perl" look OK, while "awk
>   and Perl" and "Python and perl" do
>   not.  But never write "PERL", because
>   perl is not an acronym, apocryphal
>   folklore and post-facto expansions
>   notwithstanding.

Answer (score 4):

Despite a lot of anecdote to the contrary, "PERL" was never really an acronym -- it's a "backronym".  The name Perl was chosen first, then some people jokingly applied expansions to it, which caught on.

The [PerlMonks community](http://perlmonks.org) (highly recommended!) taught me the convention, and it's similar to Java's:

- It's *never* PERL (or JAVA)
- When you're talking about the language, it's Perl (or Java)
- When you're talking about the interpreter itself, it's perl (or java).

That said, it doesn't make a whole hill of beans if you do it "wrong".

Comment: Actually those conventions were in place long before Perl Monks arrived :-)

Comment: You say "it doesn't make a whole hill of beans", but it certainly can.  Spelling it as "PERL" pegs you as someone who is not very familiar with Perl.  It's a bit of a shibboleth.

Answer (score 3):

"The name is normally capitalized (Perl) when referring to the language and uncapitalized (perl) when referring to the interpreter program itself since Unix-like file systems are case-sensitive."  From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) at time of posting.

Answer (score 3):

While, as has been said, it doesn't make THAT much difference if you get it wrong, some folks do use correct capitalization (or at least, NOT referring to 'PERL' or any of the more sensible backcronyms) as a shibboleth for clue in job ads. :)

Answer (score 2):

[Perl](http://www.perl.org/about/style-guide.html)

Answer (score 1):

perl or Perl is fine.

Comment: But they mean different things. "Perl" is the language, "perl" is the compiler.