# Is there a Ruby site like this python.mirocommunity.org (python)?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, jruby

Is there a Ruby site like this  http://python.mirocommunity.org (python videos). This is a great Python site, love to find a equivalent RUBY site any ideas? Maybe someone should start one?

Thankyou in advance ;-)

Comment: FYI: Ruby is not an acronym. It is the name of a gemstone.

Comment: @Joerg: Maybe he was thinking of [PERL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72312/how-should-i-capitalize-perl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Rails this site is very popular: http://railscasts.com/

Answer (score 1):

Something like those:

- http://rubyreflector.com/
- http://rubycorner.com/

Answer (score 1):

Not as organized as "http://python.mirocommunity.org" but you may find this useful

1. http://confreaks.net/events