# Perl array initialized incorrectly

Tags: arrays, perl

Just starting with Perl, and I used the wrong pair of parentheses for this code example:

```
@arr = {"a", "b", "c"};
print "$_\n" foreach @arr;
```

I mean, I can of course see WHAT it does when I run it, but I don't understand WHY it does that. Shouldn't that simply fail with a syntax error?

Comment: Welcome to perl.  Always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of EVERY perl script.  In this instance, you would've gotten the warning `Odd number of elements in anonymous hash` which could've also clued you in to the mistype.

Comment: @Miller: Unless the OP added a fourth element, in which case perl would proceed silently.

Comment: @Miller: And *always* spell it *Perl* ;)

Comment: @Borodin: Unless you're talking about the interpreter (as I was). :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72312/how-should-i-capitalize-perl

Comment: @Borodin, "perl" is proper if you are referring to the program/executable.

Comment: @MichaelCarman, @ikegami: My remark was a light-hearted one, as evidenced by the `;)`, and was addressed to @Miller. In any case `perlfaq1` says *"You may or may not choose to follow this usage"*, and because the line between language and interpreter can often be blurred I use *Perl* pretty much universally. *perl* is clearly wrong for the language as it is a proper name, and *PERL* is just as wrong because it is not a (real) acronym

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have accidentally created an *anonymous hash*, which is a hash that has no identifier and is accessed only by reference.

The array `@arr` is set to a single element which is a reference to that hash. Properly written it would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @arr = (
  {
    a => "b",
    c => undef,
  }
);

print "$_\n" foreach @arr;
```

which is why you got the output

```
HASH(0x3fd36c)
```

(or something similar) because that is how Perl will represent a hash reference as a string.

If you want to experiment, then you can print the value of the first hash element by using `$arr[0]` as a hash reference (the array has only a single element at index zero) and accessing the value of the element with key `a` with `print $arr[0]->{a}, "\n"`.

Note that, because hashes have to have a multiple of two values (a set of key/value pairs) the hash in your own code is implicitly expanded to four values by adding an `undef` to the end.

It is *vital* that you add `use strict` and `use warnings` to the top of every Perl program you write. In this case the latter would have raised the warning

```
Odd number of elements in anonymous hash
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer also explains why @arr is still an array, even though it was initialized as a hash.

Comment: It wasn't initialized as a hash. 1) As I explained, `{}` returns a scalar, and you can definitely assign a list of scalars to an array. (e.g. `my @a = ('a');`) 2) That would be wrong to assign to hash.

Answer (score 3):

It can be surprising how few things are syntax errors in Perl. In this case, you've stumbled onto the syntax for creating an an anonymous hash reference: `{ LIST }`. Perl doesn't require the use of parentheses (the `()` kind) when initializing an array<sup>1</sup>. Arrays hold ordered lists of scalar (single) values and references are scalars so perl happily initializes your array with that reference as the only element.

It's not what you *wanted*, but it's perfectly valid Perl.

<sub>The `()` override the precedence of the operators and thus changes the behavior of the expression. `@a = (1, 2, 3)` does what you'd expect, but `@a = 1, 2, 3` means `(@a = 1), 2, 3`, so it only assigns `1` to `@a`.</sub>

Comment: @ikegami: I was struggling to find the wording for a subtle point and failed. :( I've restored your edits.

Answer (score 2):

`{ LIST }` is the hash constructor. It creates a hash, assigns the result of `LIST` to it, and returns a reference to it.

```
my $h = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
say $h->{a};  # b
```

A list of one hash ref is just as legit as any other list, so no, it shouldn't be a syntax error.